# Angular 6 Recursive Route Definition

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am attempting to define my route tree in such a way that an arbitrary path can be taken through a tree.  The application is a database explorer, where you can navigate from one table that is displayed using a list component, to a details component, and then once you have that detail item selected, you are presented with navigation properties which will allow you to see related tables.  We give the user a starting point, but the path they take through the database can be quite random.  The best I can come up with thus far is to define the route trees as constants in feature modules that represent each table and then import the navigation property routes as children to each.  This seems to work except in one scenario... recursive routes.  The recursive definition bombs for the obvious block scoped variable used before declared... Are there any ways around this?
Example, 

`const batchRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BatchListComponent,
    resolve: { data: BatchesResolver },
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Batches',
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'new',
    component: BatchAddComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Add a New Batch',
    },
  },
  {
    path: ':batchId',
    resolve: { item: BatchResolver },
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Batches',
    },
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'edit', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'edit',
        component: BatchDetailsComponent,
        resolve: { breadcrumb: BatchBreadcrumbResolver },
      },
      {
        path: 'childbatches',
        children: batchRoutes,
      },
    ],
  },
];`

Comment: Just use a simple route that points to a single node in the tree. Don't try to persist the tree structure via the routes. That is an application state problem and not a routing problem.

Comment: The RouterState is application state, the UrlSegment[] is maintained and the resovled parameters are passed to the children.  You could recompose and point as you are saying here, but it will always look like you are very shallow in the tree vs. representing what the user actually did.  Maybe you are presenting that I should use some additional state management strategy and override the router but I think I will still have this issue.

Comment: The RouterState holds what was resolved for the current route. It is not application state. You can *infer* an application state based upon a given route, but it is an inference. How you infer application state from a route is your decision. I can give you opinions on how routes can be used, but you can disagree. Back-end developers have long used routes for server state, but routes are far broader on front-end apps. I would ask that you think about how your URLs will be used. Do you need web crawlers, bookmarks, etc. etc. then work from that perspective.

Comment: I have an Angular app that uses a tree to navigate. When the user clicks a node the route is updated with the unique ID of that node `/projects/:id`. The user can expand and go deep into the tree, but the route is always `/projects/:id`. Selecting a node changes the route, but the tree component is above the `<router-outlet>` so it's state does not change. When the page is reloaded the tree component expands all nodes until it shows `/project/:id`.

Comment: I agree with being able to create a flat route tree that can handle the display of each list and detail components.  Shortening the route and repointing to the flat portion in order to be certain we are matching a route is a good way to be certain you always have a route definition.  You lose the ability for deep linking.  In your example, how do you reflect a recursive relationship?

Comment: Can you update your question and provide an example of what a recursive relationship looks like.

Comment: Batches have Batches in the above example. I called them child batches to show the difference. But we can pick any recursive relationship for this question. ComponentA has related ComponentAs.  In many scenarios you would use some sort of lazy loading strategy with callbacks to handle this complexity.  The issue with predefined or early detection is it will just run into maximum callstack reached via the loop.  If I had an iterator function I could call here to say expand 1 more level deep if you get here at some point, and then 1 more level deep in a lazy fashion it would prevent max stack.

Comment: When the page loads you show `ComponentA` and mark it's associated links as collapsed. The user has to expand those to navigate elsewhere. When you have recursive data as such there is no path to follow. There is only a current node. You might have entry nodes (i.e. root) but that doesn't matter. If you must unfold a path back to root, then you need to use a path finding algorithm. Like the ones they use in video games. Again, this can't be represented via a route. You can only define where to start.